# system command not executing with mpiicc -O

Tags: c, optimization, mpi, intel

I have **intel Parallel studio XE cluster edition 2015** on my 10 Node server connected with infiniband band. I wrote my code in C. My code consists of system commands with sprintf command like below:

```
printf("started \n");
system("cp metis_input.txt $HOME/metis-4.0/.");
sprintf(filename,"$HOME/metis-4.0/./partdmesh metis_input.txt %d",size-1);
system(filename);
sprintf(filename,"mv metis_input.txt.npart.%d nodes_proc.txt",size-1);
system(filename);
printf("completed \n");
```

When I compile my code and run it without any opmization flags it runs smoothly but when I compile my code with **"mpiicc -O"** the above lines dont even seem to be executed. I think that the above lines are being skipped. Only the `printf`'s are executed. Do I need to add anything extra in my code (like including any headers) to get these system commands runnning for **INTEL mpi compiler with -O** ?